# xsl:apply-template to only nodes with specific attribute value

Tags: xslt, transform

I have an XML document which I'm subjected to an XSLT.  The structure is similar to:

```
<root>
  <item value="1">
     <object/>
  </item>
  <item value="2" />
     <object/>
  </item>
</root>
```

My goal is to end up with a transformed XML similar to:

```
<root>
 <parent>
  <object-one value-one="1"/>
 </parent>
 <parent>
  <object-two value-two="2"/>
 </parent>
</root>
```

My XSLT is similar to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="object" />


<xsl:template match="object">
    <xsl:call-template name="1" />
    <xsl:call-template name="2" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="1" match="object[item/@value = '1'">
  <xsl:element name="object-one" namespace="http://something.org">
    <xsl:attribute name="_Description">
      <xsl:value-of select="@_Type"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="_Type">
      <xsl:value-of select="@_Amount"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="2" match="object[item/@value = '2'">
  <xsl:element name="object-two" namespace="http://something.org">
    <xsl:attribute name="OriginalAmount">
      <xsl:value-of select="@_Amount"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is the all item nodes are having the same template applied.  How can I apply a template to only specific nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**: Now for different input sample (corrected for well-formed):

```
<root>
    <item value="1">
        <object/>
    </item>
    <item value="2" >
        <object/>
    </item>
</root>
```

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:num="number" extension-element-prefixes="num">
    <num:num>one</num:num>
    <num:num>two</num:num>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <parent>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </parent>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="object">
        <xsl:variable name="vTextNumber" select="document('')/*/num:*[number(current()/../@value)]"/>
        <xsl:element name="object-{$vTextNumber}">
            <xsl:attribute name="value-{$vTextNumber}">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@value"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <object-one value-one="1" />
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <object-two value-two="2" />
    </parent>
</root>
```

**EDIT 2**: Now, what is wrong within your stylesheet fragment? Well, it looks like you don't know how the processor resolves template rules applying, also XPath navegation.

First, this `object[item/@value = '1']` will match only this kind of input

```
<object>
    <item value="1"/>
</object>
```

Second, consider this three rules

1 -

```
<xsl:template match="object">
</xsl:template>
```

2 -

```
<xsl:template name="1" match="object[../@value = '1']"> 
</xsl:template>
```

3 -

```
<xsl:template name="2" match="object[../@value = '2']"> 
</xsl:template>
```

With your last provided input, first `object` element (in document order) will match rules 1 and 2, and then the processor would resolve to apply rule 2. Why? From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict

> Next, all matching template rules that
>   have lower priority than the matching
>   template rule or rules with the
>   highest priority are eliminated from
>   consideration. The priority of a
>   template rule is specified by the
>   priority attribute on the template
>   rule. The value of this must be a real
>   number (positive or negative),
>   matching the production Number with an
>   optional leading minus sign (-). The
>   default priority is computed as
>   follows:
>
> - If the pattern contains multiple alternatives separated by |, then it
>     is treated equivalently to a set of template rules, one for each
>     alternative.
> - If the pattern has the form of a QName preceded by a
>     ChildOrAttributeAxisSpecifier or has the form processing-instruction(Literal)
>     preceded by a ChildOrAttributeAxisSpecifier, then the priority is 0.
> - If the pattern has the form NCName:* preceded by a
>     ChildOrAttributeAxisSpecifier, then the priority is -0.25.
> - Otherwise, if the pattern consists of just a NodeTest
>     preceded by a ChildOrAttributeAxisSpecifier, then the priority is -0.5.
> - Otherwise, the priority is 0.5.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but I was unable to get the desired results.  It keeps applying only one of the two templates to every <object/>, whereas the goal is to apply both templates but only where the condition matches.

Please see my revised question with more accurate code.

Comment: The main problem I'm having is the value I'm testing for belongs to the parent of the node I'm applying the template to.

Comment: @alan: `I tried your suggestions but I was unable to get the desired results` Well, **you've changed the input and desired output**! The best practice would be to ask another question. Otherwise you should add those news to your question, but not replacing. Take a look to my edit. If there is something not clear to you from my own stylesheet, just specificly ask.

Comment: @Alejandro:  I'm sorry if I was not clear, the element names are arbitrary, I am not trying to convert the values to part of the name.  The problem is I need to test a value of the <item/> element; based on @value I need to apply one of two templates to the <object/> element, these two templates (though based on <object/>) will result in different element names.

Comment: @alan: There is no general solutions. In declarative paradigm you must map an specific input to an specific output (or at least with well known schema). So, I can only explain to you what is wrong with your own template. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks!  My problem was in how I was specifying the parent element in my match, namely: match="object[item/@value = '1']" whereas I needed to use match="object[../@value = '1']"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make your matches more specific:

```
<xsl:template name="item1" match="item[@value=1]">
    <xsl:element name="item" namespace="http://something.org">
        <xsl:attribute name="_Description">
            <xsl:value-of select="@_Type"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="_Type">
            <xsl:value-of select="@_Amount"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="item2" match="item[@value=2]">
    <xsl:element name="item2_item" namespace="http://something.org">
        <xsl:attribute name="OriginalAmount">
            <xsl:value-of select="@_Amount"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've attempted to implement your suggestions but I still only get one template applied to all <object/> nodes.